# Cheap and simple step-up converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I would like to build simple and small power supply for my projects with microcontrollers. This supply should be powered by two Ni-MH batteries and output should be 5V (maximum current 500mA).

I know there are plenty of them on the Intenet ([MintyBoost](http://www.adafruit.com/products/14) from Adafruit and [cheap ones from China](http://www.ebay.com/itm/140891808636?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) on eBay) but I want to build one by myself.

The [LTC3400](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3400) looks very good but not cheap. Do you know any other step-up converter (Vin 1.8V and less, output current 500mA and more)? By cheap, I mean circa $1.

Comment: There you go; [LM2623](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM2623ALD%2FNOPB/LM2623ALD%2FNOPBCT-ND/565213) for starters. Good luck soldering :) Also, click [here](http://goo.gl/9nYaq) for more..

Comment: Microchip has some good stuff in that voltage range too.

Answer (score 1):

Olin's right about Microchip doing some nice switching regulators - I use the [MCP1603](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0d2a/0900766b80d2a2a2.pdf) parts quite regularly. However these are buck regulators and don't have a 5V fixed option anyway. I just had a quick look on Farnell and didn't notice any MC parts that fit for this requirement. It may be worth a look on their website though.

The cheapest 5V boost regulator I am aware of that can work down below 1.8V at 500mA is the [NCP1450](http://uk.farnell.com/on-semiconductor/ncp1450asn50t1g/dc-dc-step-up-converter-5-0v-smd/dp/1460676) from ON Semi. It's £0.63 in qty 1, can source up to 1A, and can startup with low as 0.8V with no load. It comes in a nice and small 5-pin SOT-25 type package.
I haven't used it, but I saved it whilst searching for another regulator as it looked like a nice part. ON Semi make a lot of decent cheap parts in this category.